# Handshaking of Master Slave In Jenkins shows Connecting but doesn't get Connected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I am trying to establish master slave connection between two system.So I have configured a node Myslave as given in Jenkins Master Slave Documentation(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)

But  when I try to connect to the master on the slave system the Jenkins Slave Agent shows Connecting to master(i.e my system ip address) but doesn't connect.

There is no error.I am not able to determine the problem.

Comment: Why don't you try running it(slave.jar) by hand from terminal ?

Comment: I tried it through terminal and through browser but i am getting the same error

Comment: What command did you run ? Did you turn on debugging ?

Comment: javaws http://my system Ip/computer/SlaveS/slave-agent.jnlp from command line. and I Use Launch Button from Browser to download the slave agent

Comment: I dont know how to turn on debugging